# Value of DB not being passed on Modal but is being passed on the page itself

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I have an applicant list page where I generate each applicant in the page using this code:

```
<% ApplicantDAO applicantDAO = new ApplicantDAO();%>
<% for (int i = 0; i < applicantDAO.viewApplicant().size(); i++) {%>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">

            <div class="list-group">

                <a class="list-group-item active">
                    <img src="th_1x1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive Image" width="100%" height="100">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" id="guardName<%=+i%>" id="guardName<%=+i%>"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantFirstName() + " "%>
                        <%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantLastName()%></h4>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item">
                    <p class="list-group-item-text" id="applyingFor<%=+i%>" id="applyingFor<%=+i%>"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplyingFor()%></p>
                </a>
                <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" href="#moreDetails">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="moreDetails<%=+i%>">More Details</button>
                </a>

                ...
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Then in the more details button there is a modal with this code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="moreDetails">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Applicant Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2 class="text-center"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantLastName() + ", "%><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantFirstName()%></h2>
                <table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
                    <thead id="tblHead">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Category</th>
                        <th class="text-right">Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Height</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantHeight() + "cm"%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Weight</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantWeight() + "kg"%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Address</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantAddress()%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Contact Number</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantContactNumber()%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Email</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantEmail()%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Gender</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantGender()%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Applying For</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplyingFor()%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Age</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantAge()%></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">Applicant Notes</td>
                        <td class="text-right"><%=applicantDAO.viewApplicant().get(i).getApplicantNotes()%></td>

                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

What I want to happen is that when I open the other applicant's modals, they should display the details of that applicant, but what happens is that only the first applicant's details appears. What should I do?

Comment: if you create a modal for applicant make sure not using the same id for the modal  `id="moreDetails" `. the id is unique in the html so it open the same modal.

Comment: I tried doing this: id=MoreDetails<%+=+i%>. In my understanding, the id will increment thus, generating different ids. But when i click the button, theres no modal that pops up. only a dimmed screen. It also happened the same with trying uuid. thanks!

Comment: you have to change the href of open modal `<a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" href="#moreDetails">` must have the same id for each applicant

Comment: What do you mean by that? I did not quite understand what you told me. im sorry

Comment: for each modal has an id #moreDetails1 #moreDetails2. To open the modal  you must have the href attribute of `data-toggle="modal` the same value of the id. so for modal with #moreDetails1 the link element that open the modal must be <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" href="#moreDetails1"> and so on. in your case just change to <a class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" href="#moreDetails<%=+i%>">

Comment: But I am using an loop to generate all of these so I cant manually put different ids.. I tried doing href=#moreDetails<%+=i%> but when I do that nothing is happening when I press the button

Comment: Nothing is happening when I do that. When I click the button there were no changes at all.

Comment: if you see the html generated in the browser can you check if the id are generated correctly. It will work only if the id of modal is the same of the href

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciated your help :) It works now

Answer (score 0):

this is  a working jsp with multi modal. the important thing is that the modal id must be the same of href value that toggle the modal.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <% for(int i = 0 ; i<=10;i++){ %>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%=i%>">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<%=i%>" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <%}%>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```